# Extract special characters from a text in C#

Tags: c#

```
 Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.631]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\amir8\OneDrive\Desktop\C#\CmdCommand\CmdCommand\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [172.217.18.142] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.18.142: bytes=32 **time=90ms** TTL=127
Reply from 172.217.18.142: bytes=32 **time=83ms** TTL=127
Reply from 172.217.18.142: bytes=32 **time=71ms** TTL=127
Reply from 172.217.18.142: bytes=32 **time=70ms** TTL=127

Ping statistics for 172.217.18.142:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 70ms, Maximum = 90ms, Average = 78ms

C:\Users\amir8\OneDrive\Desktop\C#\CmdCommand\CmdCommand\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows>exit
```

***I have this text and I want to extract the amount of time (I showed by * in code) from this text and put it in a variable, but given that the number of characters in the string is not known (for example, the number of characters in the first three lines is not fixed) how can I Let me do this.***

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string line = "";
            string pattern = @"time=(?'time'\d+)";
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("Reply from"))
                {
                    Match match = Regex.Match(line,pattern);
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["time"].Value);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something along these lines work (obviously you will need to expand based on multiple **times** being in the string content)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var mydata = "Reply from 172.217.18.142: bytes=32 **time=90ms** TTL=127";
        var pattern = @"\*\*time=(.*)ms\*\*";
    
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);      
    
        Match m = r.Match(mydata);
        if (m.Success) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]); // will write '90'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0) for that. Ex:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(yourString, @"time=\d+ms");

foreach(var match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```